# Duplicate Document ID In Document Library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, document-id

I have a document library in SharePoint 2013 that has a few documents with the same document ID. Is there anyway I can regenerate this without reuploading the documents?

I've tried the fix mentioned [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53076/how-to-fix-multiple-documents-with-same-document-id) for SharePoint 2010 but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can reset the all document Id in a site
please look at this post

http://sharepointconnoisseur.blogspot.in/2012/04/reset-all-document-ids-in-this-site.html

Comment: Will this give me new document ID's for all existing documents that don't have duplicates.

Comment: Yes. you will get new document id for all documents

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to do so in the UX! But you can update a Document ID programmatically. The ID is stored in the list item field named **_dlc_DocId** and the redirect link in **_dlc_DocIdUrl**. Using the [SharePoint PnP PowerShell cmdlets](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell), you can easily regenerate your duplicate Document IDs like I'm doing in the example below:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://hostname/sites/site
$file = Get-PnPFile "Shared Documents/Test.docx"
$file.ListItemAllFields["_dlc_DocId"] = "YourNewID"
$file.ListItemAllFields.SystemUpdate()
Execute-PnPQuery
```

You do not need to update the **_dlc_DocIdUrl** value as the Document ID event receiver will in turn update and align it with the new ID. However, beware that the Document ID redirect link will not work until search has reindexed the document!